# Como guardar en un archivo wav una señal de audio modificada en python

Tags: python, numpy, wav

Necesito generar un archivo wav con la señal modificada de sonido, la variable nuevo contiene la señal modificada, como seria el proceso para guardar esa señal y que me genere un archivo de audio de dos canales en formato .wav con dicha señal

```
import  numpy as np
import soundfile as sf
import  sounddevice as sd

retraso=22050

x, FS = sf.read('acdc-stereo.wav', dtype='float')
print(x)
zeros = np.zeros(retraso-1,dtype='float')
h = np.concatenate(([1],zeros,[0.3]))

print('Procesando..')
y = np.convolve(x[:,0],h, mode="full")
nuevo=(y,FS)
print(y)
print('Reproducionedo señal original')
sd.play(x,FS)
sd.wait()
print("reproducienod señal de salida ")
sd.play(nuevo)
sd.wait()
```

Comment: Me surge una duda, procesas un solo canal con np.convolve pero quieres unas salida estéreo ¿qué pasa con el otro canal? ¿ambos canales con los mismos datos (falso estéreo)? ¿usar canal sin modificar del archivo original (uno alterado y el otro no)? ¿aplicar procesado también al otro canal?

Comment: @FJSevilla también aplicar el mismo procesado al otro canal pero hasta el momento no he encontrado la forma de hacerlo, ya que he leído que convolve solo funciona con arreglos 1d y el audio del archivo me devuelve un arreglo 2d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo suelo usar **librosa** para manejar el audio.

```
#Cargamos el audio
audio, signal_rate = librosa.load(audios/archivo_audio.wav, duration=5.0)

#Guardamos el audio
librosa.output.write_wav('audios/nuevo_audio.wav', audio, signal_rate)
```

En este caso, mi "signal rate" es tú "retraso".